# PHPUnit does not work when I run the tests on the Laravel framework, I get the error of /usr/bin/php declares an invalid value for PHP_VERSION

Tags: php, macos, testing, phpunit

I am trying to run my test file, ImportCSVTest.php with the command
./vendor/bin/phpunit --filter=testNoImportFile

but I get the error of

```
/usr/bin/php declares an invalid value for PHP_VERSION.
This breaks fundamental functionality such as version_compare().
Please use a different PHP interpreter.
```

My test file, ImportCSVTest.php is as follows

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ImportCSVTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testNoImportFile()
    {
        Storage::fake('products');

        $response = $this->json('POST', '/import', [
            'csv' => UploadedFile::fake()->create('emptyUpload', 0, null)
        ]);

        Storage::disk('products')->assertMissing('emptyUpload');
    }


}
```

First time I am coming across an error like this, how does one fix this?

Comment: Try running `which php` and see if it is using the same path.

Comment: /usr/bin/php, thats what i get when i enter that command, now what?

Comment: Try doing `php -v` to see what it outputs

Comment: PHP 7.3.24 thats the version of PHP im using

Comment: But it outputs correctly without errors, right ?

Comment: yes, no errors at all when i enter php -v, the full output is this

`WARNING: PHP is not recommended
PHP is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software.
Future versions of macOS will not include PHP.
PHP 7.3.24-(to be removed in future macOS) (cli) (built: Dec 21 2020 21:33:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.24, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies`

Comment: Oh, you are using mac... I don't know if that warning is the problem or not, your error is pretty strange. I would recommend you to use Docker

Comment: fixed it now, just upgraded my php to the latest version, all seems to be working now

Comment: I think upgrading PHP away from system version is not a bad idea, however there seems to be a fix in Phpunit as well from a couple of days ago and that might also levitate the issue. some more info: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/2b0a4bb65811306a09d62d4c406b9d060baa8480 and https://bbqsoftwares.com/blog/phpunit-big-sur . give it a try and check if everything works, you then should leave it as an answer as one solution.

Comment: Oohh, so that is the issue... I thought so when I saw what he shared...

Answer (score 9):

PHPUnit refuses to be run with a PHP interpreter where the value of the `PHP_VERSION` constant contains an invalid value due to modification made by vendors that ship (binary) distributions of PHP.

`7.3.24-(to be removed in future macOS)` is such an invalid value. The `-(to be removed in future macOS)` suffix was added by Apple, who is the vendor of the PHP interpreter binary you use.

[Here](https://bbqsoftwares.com/blog/phpunit-big-sur) is a great article that explains the background. [Here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/8.5.17/ChangeLog-8.5.md#8517---2021-06-23) is the ChangeLog for PHPUnit 8.5.17. [Here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/9.5.6/ChangeLog-9.5.md#956---2021-06-23) is the ChangeLog for PHPUnit 9.5.6. These are the first versions of PHPUnit that check for invalid values of `PHP_VERSION` on startup.

**TL;DR:** Do not use the PHP interpreter that is shipped by Apple with macOS. Use Homebrew, or similar, instead.